# android studio sending string array put extra to new activity

Tags: android-listview

Hello im working on a school project. I have a list of strings on a listview. I want to have the user make a selection add that to a string array and then print out the string array in a new listview in a different activity.

Here's what I have so far:

This sends the data:

```
        public class Walmart extends ActionBarActivity {

            ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();



            Intent i = new Intent(Walmart.this,GiftsSelected.class);

        private String[]giftarray = {


              //filled with strings of items

                };

         private ListView giftListView;
         private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

         public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){}
         public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){

             return true;
             }

         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.activity_walmart);
             getSupportActionBar().hide();
             giftListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gift_list1);
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, giftarray );
            giftListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

             giftListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String item = giftarray[position];
            addv(item);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             } }); }

     public void addv(String y){
         x.add(y);

         Intent m = new Intent(Walmart.this,GiftsSelected.class);
         m.putStringArrayListExtra("list",x);
         startActivity(m);

        }
```

this should recieve the string array list and show it in the listview to the user however it crashes:

```
    public class GiftsSelected extends ActionBarActivity {

            private ListView giftListView;
            private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();



         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("list");


    if(list.equals(null) == false) {
      arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, list);
    }else{

     String[] giftarray = new String[100];
      giftarray[0] = "NOthing added yet";
      arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, giftarray);

          }

             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_gifts_selected);
              getSupportActionBar().hide();

              giftListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gift_list1);
               giftListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
              giftListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

Any help would be appreciated if you have a better way of doing this please let me know or examples that send an array to a new activities listview would help too. Thanks for your time

Comment: Need more details on the progres. What is it doing now?  Is the Listview displaying data? Is clicking an item on the Listview working?  Besides that, I can only see an issue with sending the data.

Comment: Thanks for looking, Well from activity one i make a selection and it adds to activity two and opens it immediately. That's working now but on my main screen I have a button that I click that opens activity2 and it crashes. And the line with getintent () is the reason it's crashing.

Comment: I posted an answer for you....

Comment: Was the posted answer helpful to you also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is good Google documentation @ [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).  Search text for "**android:parentActivityName**", under "Create the activity without Android Studio" section 4. The sample sets the **AndroidManifest**.xml for the **android:parentActivityName** attribute to the package name of the first activity, as in your scenario. The sample AndroidManifest:

```
<application ... >
    ...
    <activity
        android:name="com.mycompany.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MyActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MyActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Notes:

- I hope `getIntent()`, used in OnCreate() on Activity 2, does not return null anymore after this fix.
- I found out getIntent() is deprecated in API level 4, instead use **parseUri**().
  Code example using partially from your code (please fix the URI string to the actual name):

> ```
> intent = Intent.parseUri("content://com.android.WalmartActivity", 0);
> if(intent != null)
> {
>    list = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("list");
> }
> ```

Comment: @bp01442, I m glad for you. Just want to know, which one worked?  Did you try both, the first or second bullet under the Notes section?  You may also vote this answer to be helpful by clicking on the up-arrow icon besides the posed answer.  Thanks...

Comment: It was a combination of both and some other helpful stuff on the web. Apparently the way androidstudio is set up it was crashing my app if i didn't immediately open a new activity when a selection is made.